# PHP - Spot the difference - Image Processing

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick, omr

Since i'm not much into image processing in PHP, however being familiar about OCR & OMR, i'm having a unique requirement. Here's the Scenario:

Given Input: 2 Images

- Image 1: A garden
- Image 2: Same Garden with a person standing

Required Output: Separate out the person standing

Any technical pointers towards the topic will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This would be a good question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ because it is mostly discussion of potential algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Imagick Compare function  .. this can help you identify the slightest difference between images

```
  compare a.png a1.png diff.png
```

Compare

[image]
[image]

Result

[image]

Run

```
 convert diff.png -matte ( +clone -fuzz 5% -transparent #f3303e ) -compose DstOut -composite red-channel.png
```

[image]

- [See Documentation and Example](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/)
- [PHP DOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.compareimages.php)

Comment: @Syed Absar you are welcome....